# sbt Downloading test artifacts from the web

Tags: scala, sbt, integration-testing

If I have a large test data set which I store somewhere, say in an S3 bucket or other HTTP accessible location, what is the best approach to creating a task in sbt which would download these test data resources to some project folder for integration tests?

As these files are large (few 100MB), I'd rather not store them in source control.

Ideally I'd like to have a task like; `sbt downloadTestData`

Are there any plugins out there which support getting files or internal sbt api for getting web uris?

Comment: you can easily implement this as a custom task